# Can I set List Validation Settings programmatically?

Tags: list, validation, pnp, provisioning

I want to set the Validation Settings of a List with PnPJS. Is this possible?

alternatively: Is it possible to provision a List with specific Validation Settings in place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to set validation for a list field using JSOM,

```
$(document)  
    .ready(function()  
    {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', SetValidation);  
    });  
varoList, clientContext;  

function SetValidation()  
{  
    //Get client context ,web and list object  
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    varoWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = oWeb.get_lists()  
        .getByTitle('DemoList');  
    //Load the client context and execute the batch  
    clientContext.load(oList);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Success, Failure);  
}  

function Success()  
{  
    //Set validation formula  
    oList.set_validationFormula("[StartDate] < TODAY()");  
    oList.set_validationMessage('Validation Failed ! Start Date should be less than Today.');  
    oList.update();  
    //Load the client context and execute the batch  
    clientContext.load(oList);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);  
}  

function Failure(sender, args)  
{  
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n'  
        args.get_stackTrace());  
}  

function OnSuccess()  
{  
    console.log("List validation formula has been set for this list");  
}  

function OnFailure(sender, args)  
{  
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
} <  
/script>
```

Using the above code you will have an idea on setting the validation rule, now refer the below link to do the same using pnp js.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/listlibrary-fieldcolumn-manipulation-using-pnp-js-core/

To know more about the jsom implementation refer the below link,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-validation-formula-for-lists-in-sharepoint-2016-and-office-365-using-javascr/